# Posix C non blocking read socket

Tags: c, sockets, select, posix

I'm trying to create thread to read from socket descriptor. Need doing this with non blocking loop to check current time and close socket after session end, but `FD_ISSET` returns 0 even if on socket can read data.

```
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(session_ref->fd, &fds);

while(1)
{
    while(1)
    {
        FD_CLR(session_ref->fd, &fds);
        FD_SET(session_ref->fd, &fds);
        n = select( session_ref->fd, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout ); // n = 0 
        if( FD_ISSET( session_ref->fd, &fds ) )
            break;
        else 
        {
            // some operations
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    n = read( session_ref->fd, buffer, 2048 );
    printf("Read: %i\n", n);
}
```

Where i made a mistake?

Comment: You are not checking `n == 1`

Comment: but n also is equal 0

Comment: You are passing `fd` in the first parameter of `select()`. You need to pass `fd+1` instead. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the highest file descriptor value + 1, that's why `n == 0`

```
n = select( session_ref->fd, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout ); // n = 0
```

has to be

```
n = select( 1 + session_ref->fd, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout ); // n = 0
```

and then check how many files in the set are ready

```
if ((n > 1) && (FD_ISSET( session_ref->fd, &fds ) != 0))
```

in your case, since there is only one file in the set, it would actually be

```
if ((n == 1) && (FD_ISSET( session_ref->fd, &fds ) != 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the socket is 4, you need `select` to look for at least five possible sockets, 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. So your first parameter to `select` is one too few.